# what can we say about $\mathrm{E}(y^HC_{yy}^{-1}y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

suppose $y$ is a continuous random vector with zero mean, but with unkonwn(or arbitrary) pdf,
$C_{yy}$ is the covariance matrix of y, then what can we say about
$$
 \mathrm{E}(y^HC_{yy}^{-1}y)
$$
? $E(.)$ is the expected value.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that we have 
\begin{align*}
  \def\E{\mathbf E}\E[y^* C_{yy}^{-1}y] &= \E\left[\sum_{i,j} \bar y_i \bigl(C_{yy}^{-1}\bigr)_{ij} y_j\right]\\
   &= \sum_{i,j} \bigl(C_{yy}^{-1}\bigr)_{ij} \E[\bar y_i y_j]\\
   &= \sum_{i,j} \bigl(C_{yy}^{-1}\bigr)_{ij} \bigl(C_{yy}\bigr)_{ji}\\
   &= \operatorname{tr} C_{yy}^{-1}C_{yy}\\
   &= n.
\end{align*}

Comment: thank you :) , the second $ij$ should be $ji$.